# Mysql2::Error:... when calling `near` in geocoder gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

So i have a list of services all geocoded with geogoder gem.

Calling `Service.near("London")` throws

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in
>       your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
>       server version for the right syntax to use near

`Service.near("London").to_sql`

gives

```
SELECT services.*, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((services.longitude - -4.8824474) / 57.2957795), 
      ((services.latitude - 36.510071) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing 
FROM `services` 
WHERE (services.latitude BETWEEN 36.220607433778305 AND 36.7995345662217 
    AND services.longitude BETWEEN -5.242587667147616 AND -4.522307132852385 
    AND () BETWEEN 0.0 AND 20)  
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

`distance_between`works with no problems.

Can anyone advise what i did wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point i had obviously added and then removed Geokit gem.

Left in the model was acts_as_mappable

This caused the SQL syntax to be thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the correct parameters in order for the Geocoder gem to synthesize working SQL.

In the [gem documentation](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/), though admittedly not explicit about it, you need all of the parameters to be fully specified

```
nearbys = Place.near("Omaha, NE", 50,:order => "distance")
```

Generically

```
   nearbys = Model.near("Gecodeable address string", N (range constant), order: parameter)
```

For your case, I'd suggest trying the below to see if that gets you past the MySQL error

```
@result = Service.near("London, UK", YOUR_DISTANCE_CONSTANT, order: false)
```

I don't know how helpful this is but this is the SQL .near generates for one of my models. I am passing geocoordinates and testing an "active" flag:

`[1m[36mAnimalRescue Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  animal_rescues.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((30.326374 - animal_rescues.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(30.326374 * PI() / 180) * COS(animal_rescues.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-97.771258 - animal_rescues.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((animal_rescues.longitude - -97.771258) / 57.2957795), ((animal_rescues.latitude - 30.326374) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing FROM "animal_rescues" WHERE "animal_rescues"."active_listing" = 't' AND (animal_rescues.latitude BETWEEN 29.77639322417878 AND 30.876354775821223 AND animal_rescues.longitude BETWEEN -98.40842692015944 AND -97.13408907984056 AND (3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((30.326374 - animal_rescues.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(30.326374 * PI() / 180) * COS(animal_rescues.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-97.771258 - animal_rescues.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 38)  ORDER BY delivery_item_count + dropoff_item_count DESC LIMIT 3[0m`

Comment: Thanks, but tried this already, no matter how many params i pass it throws same error. The gem actually defaults the last 2 params so you do not need to set them. The odd thing it it works perfectly on another model in the same app.

Comment: You can't just pass "London" it's not geocodable. And you do need a distance to range limit what "near" means.

Comment: I do wish you good luck with a resolution. I use geocoder and .near extensively and have seen invalid SQL generated with .near if you don't fully specify the parameters, that's why I mentioned it. But maybe you'll find a way around it.

Comment: Surprisingly it does work on my other model, but for Service not. I have tried `Service.near([LON,LAT])`, `Service.near(Service.last)`. The SQL it produces is very different from what it should, only on this model

Comment: Smells like a column type issue in this model. Maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the SQL added, very similar to my location Model output, which works. Must have done something really odd to break this! :)